How do we work with the business logic in DDD if we need to work with all users?
If we are working with a specific user and we need to know his position, for example, we can call the user entity and its getPosition() method.
What if we need to know if there is a single user with a specific position in the system. Where to implement it and how?
Question about implementation in DDD
